# Does there exists a continuous injective map $f:\mathbb{S^2}\longrightarrow RP^2\times S^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Does there a continuous injective map $f:\mathbb{S^2}\longrightarrow RP^2\times S^1$ of the form $f(x)=(p(x),g(x))$ where $p(x):\mathbb{S^2}\longrightarrow RP^2$ is universal covering and for some $g(x):\mathbb{S^2}\longrightarrow S^1?$

Here $RP^2$ denotes a real projective plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function $x \rightarrow (g(x),h(x))$ is injective, if and only if, $g(x)=g(y)$ and $h(x)=h(y)$ implies $x=y$. In this case, $g$ is the covering map $S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ and this map has the property that if $g(x)=g(y)$, then $x \neq y$ implies $x=-y$. So in order to come up with an injective $f$ as you ask, it is equivalent to find a map $S^2 \rightarrow S^1$ such that no two antipodal points map to the same point in $S^1$. Since $S^1$ canonically embeds into $\mathbb{R}^2$, the Borsuk-Ulam theorem implies this is impossible.